# jOOQ DAO for insert of one pojo does not use current connection from transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, jooq, transactional

With jOOQ 3.9.1 I generated Pojos, Daos, Records, Tables and validations.

A UserService class with a method called from a test, this class as the @Transactional.
This service is called, it has Transactional so a transaction is started, I create a new user, the same method get the id of that new user then add a role and call another method within that service to add a default quota, it is after the debug log "Try to change quota for User" that I get a org.jooq.exception.NoDataFoundException("Exactly one row expected for refresh. Record does not exist in database.") .
It seems that the Dao does not reuse the same connection or same transaction therefore it does not see the new user as it is not committed yet.

Does jOOQ have a bug/issue? Or I misconfigured?

But if I override the insert for one object with the create, it does not have any problem and the transaction is kept then committed.
Without override and passing 2 objects (and more) for the insert in QuotaHistory the dao works (see the code from jooq it does not call same method whether the collection passed has 1 or more elements)

```
public User createUser(String username, String login, String password, String email, String locale) {
    if (!loginRegex.matcher(login).matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Login does not match pattern");
    }

    final Role defaultRole = roleRepository.fetchOneByName(RoleConstants.USER);

    final String salt = RandomUtil.generateSalt();

    final Timestamp timestamp = dateTimeService.getCurrentTimestamp();

    final User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setLogin(login);
    // ... others set here

    userRepository.insert(newUser);

    final User userInserted = userRepository.fetchOneByLogin(login);

    userHasRoleRepository.insert(new UserHasRole(userInserted.getId(), defaultRole.getId()));   

    // This method call another method within the UserSevice, it simply insert a new row in another table for user quota with primary key the user id and the DateTime of the insert
    // It calls the DAO generated by jOOQ
    changeQuotaByLogin(newUser.getLogin(), applicationProperties.getUser().getQuotaDefault());

    log.debug("Created User: {}", userInserted);
    return userInserted;
}

public void changeQuotaByLogin(String login, int quota) {
    Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.fetchOneByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin())).map(userLogged -> {
        Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.fetchOneByLogin(login)).ifPresent(userToModify -> {
            log.debug("Before create local UserQuotaHistory");
            final UserQuotaHistory userQuotaHistory = new UserQuotaHistory(userToModify.getId(), dateTimeService.getCurrentTimestamp(), quota, userLogged.getId());
            log.debug("Try to change quota for User: {} by {}", userToModify, userLogged);
            userQuotaHistoryRepository.insert(userQuotaHistory);
             userToModify.setUpdateTime(dateTimeService.getCurrentTimestamp());                
            userRepository.update(userToModify);
            log.debug("Changed quota for User: {} by {}", userToModify, userLogged);
        });
        return userLogged;
    }).orElseThrow(() -> {
        log.error("Tried to change quota but no user logged, tried to modify {}", login);
        return new IllegalStateException("There is no logged user");
    });
}
```

In order to keep daos for now, I had to override the insert when only one object is passed in my repository that extends generated dao. Create is a dependency injection of the dsl.

```
@Repository
public class UserQuotaHistoryRepository extends UserQuotaHistoryDao {
private final DSLContext create;
@Autowired
public UserQuotaHistoryRepository(Configuration configuration, DSLContext create) {
    super(configuration);
    this.create = create;
}
@Override
public void insert(UserQuotaHistory u){
    create.insertInto(USER_QUOTA_HISTORY)
        .set(USER_QUOTA_HISTORY.USER_ID, u.getUserId())
        .set(USER_QUOTA_HISTORY.CREATE_TIME, u.getCreateTime())
        .set(USER_QUOTA_HISTORY.QUOTA, u.getQuota())
        .set(USER_QUOTA_HISTORY.CHANGED_BY_USER_ID, u.getChangedByUserId())
        .execute();
}
}
```

My persistence config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContextConfiguration {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceContextConfiguration.class);

private Environment env;

@Autowired
public PersistenceContextConfiguration(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

    try {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyConnectionDataSource() {
    return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(dataSource());
}

@Bean
public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource() {
    return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(lazyConnectionDataSource());
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(lazyConnectionDataSource());
}

@Bean
public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
    return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(transactionAwareDataSource());
}

@Bean
public JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer() {
    return new JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer();
}

@Bean
public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
    DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();

    jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
    jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(
        jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer()
    ));

    String sqlDialectName = env.getRequiredProperty("jooq.sql.dialect");
    SQLDialect dialect = SQLDialect.valueOf(sqlDialectName);
    jooqConfiguration.set(dialect);

    return jooqConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
    DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());

    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(
        new ClassPathResource(env.getRequiredProperty("db.schema.script"))
    );

    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
    return initializer;
}
}
```

Comment: I'd love to help, but it's really hard from your existing question to guess 1) what is really the problem, 2) where does the problem happen 3) how could I possibly reproduce it, etc. For instance, there's a `refresh()` call in your error message, but I don't see any in the code. Or you didn't show any stack trace either...

Comment: At the line userQuotaHistoryRepository.insert(userQuotaHistory); I get the exception "org.jooq.exception.NoDataFoundException" because apparently the user I inserted before (but not committed yet as I am still in the @Transactional) is not seen by the insert method to add a quota to that user

Comment: The only place where a `NoDataFoundException` is thrown by jOOQ is inside of the `refresh()` method. I'd love to see where that is called in your code, but I can't see that without a stack trace. Would you mind posting that stack trace?

Comment: I have just checkout on my mac, I commented the override of the insert in my repository and launched the application and also the tests, it worked without any problem. Strange...but I updated my dependencies 2 days ago so maybe I fixed the bug without noticing. I will check Monday on the other computer I work if the bug persist. By the way, on my mac the app takes 6 seconds to start and and 6 seconds to execute SQL script (initialise database) but on Windows 10 it takes 2 minutes...

Comment: Well, what can I do about that "mac vs windows" remark? I could maybe suggest you delete some games that run in the background of your windows computer? ;)

Comment: It works on my other computer, I do not remember there was a refresh() in my code but I certainly did then removed later. About "mac vs windows" nothing to say it was just an observation when I tried on my mac; I have not games that run in the background ;) neither any installed. Thank you for your help.